# Create two or more APIs with same URL in play framework

Tags: scala, api, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have use case where I need to read value from query string.
Currently I have two different APIs(Some other person has created the code) which maps to same URL

```
GET  /service/class/:className/details  controllers.Student.getStudentDetails(studentId)
GET  /service/class/:className/details  controllers.Student.getAllStudentsDetails()
```

If query string is present in URL then API1 should execute, otherwise API2.

As URL is same for both APIs, I am able to hit only get-student-details API(Because it has higher priority in routes file).
I am looking for alternatives to fix this problem.

As per my knowledge we don't need to create different APIs just to handle query strings.
I am thinking to merge 2 different APIs in single APIs which takes action depending upon presence of query string in request.

What I want to know is if there is way to execute two different APIs which maps to same URL(Only difference is with query string).

NOTE: I am using play 2.4.6.

Answer (score 1):

I see few ways using a single controller function (say we chose `getStudentDetails`)

1) Having an `Option` parameter:

```
  def getStudentDetails(studentId: Option[String]) = Action { studentId match {
      case Some(id) => // do something
      case None => // do something else
    }
    // ..
  }
```

2) Look for your query string parameters inside your http request:

```
  def getStudentDetails = Action { request =>
    request.queryString.get("studentId") match {
        case Some(list) => // do something...beware this is a List
        case None => // do something else
    }
    //...
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I am thinking to fix in same way that you suggested.

Comment: But currently we are having two different APIs for these cases, but play allows to hit only one API. Doesn't fixing route file will solve the problem(Play will allow to hit both APIs)?

Comment: Oh yeah of course you need to change your `routes`. I was only answering on the merging those two functions together.